# Silverlight Browser back button to work

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my Silverlight app how can I determine if the Back button is pressed and to not logout, as it is currently doing. I may have a problem as the app is primarily a grid with drill down but at least if it could return to the start page, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to trap that is with javascript.  And the only thing you can do that way is to get an OK Cancel standard messagebox.

Or what you can do if you want to manage different pages with silvelight; create a Silverlight Navigation application (with the appropritate template).